# Mysql stored procedure insert into multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Am trying to insert data into 2 tables but only 1 table gets the data but the other one doesn't. I don't get any error messages but only the login table gets populated but the user doesn't.

Here is my code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_user`(
    _email varchar(50), 
    _password varchar(255), 
    _name varchar(35), 
    _surname varchar(35)
)
BEGIN

start transaction;

    insert into logins_copy (
    email, 
    password, 
    created_at, 
    updated_at
    ) 
    values 
    (
    _email, 
    _password, 
    current_timestamp(),
    current_timestamp()
    );

    SELECT @user_id :=  id from logins_copy where email = _email;

    insert into users (
    user_id,
    name, 
    surname, 
    updated_at
    ) 
    values 
    (
    @user_id,
    _name, 
    _surname, 
    current_timestamp()
    );
    commit;

END
```

and to test this I called the procedure:

```
call `new_user`("test@hotmail.com", "test123", "Adam", "James");
```

Comment: 1. You should not be using session variable in the code (`@user_id`), but a local variable (`declare variable_name`). 2. Use `select into` and `last_insert_id()` to populate the local variable. 3. Do not assume that the insertions succeed, do error handling in your code.

Comment: @Shadow  sorry to ask, I tried fiddling with it and i couldn't get it to work. Could you show an example?

Comment: @Shadow i figured it out, thanks for the guidance